# Problems with running Factor Model in Julia

Tags: julia, factor-analysis

as part of my master's thesis, I have to carry out a factor analysis in the programming language Julia. I´m using FactorModel from the Factotum Package to carry out the Factor analysis. Since im new to Julia, i have some issues in understanding the Error Messages. I understand that there seems to be an issue with my data type, but i can´t figure out how to properly adjust my data. I would be grateful for any help.

```
   using CSV
   using Factotum
   using MathProgBase
   using ForwardDiff
   using Ipopt
   using DataFrames
   using Statistics
   using LinearAlgebra
   using Dates



  Xrel = CSV.read("C:\\Users\\Lukas\\Documents\\Xrel.csv", header = 
  false, DataFrame)
  Drel = CSV.read("C:\\Users\\Lukas\\Documents\\Drel.csv", header=false, DataFrame)
  Xcon = CSV.read("C:\\Users\\Lukas\\Documents\\Xcon.csv", header=false, DataFrame)
  Dcon = CSV.read("C:\\Users\\Lukas\\Documents\\Dcon.csv", header=false, DataFrame)

 Xrel1 = Matrix(Xrel[:,1:7])
 Drel1 = Matrix(Drel[:,1:1])
 fm = FactorModel(Xrel1.*100) #Here the error message occurs

 
 MethodError: no method matching FactorModel(::Matrix{Float64})
 Closest candidates are:
 FactorModel(::M, !Matched::M, !Matched::V, !Matched::M, !Matched::M, 
 !Matched::M, !Matched::M, !Matched::M) where {M<:(AbstractMatrix{T} 
 where T), V<:(AbstractVector{T} where T)} at 
 C:\Users\Lukas\.julia\packages\Factotum\KzSyl\src\Factotum.jl:14
 FactorModel(::AbstractMatrix{G}, !Matched::Any; kwargs...) where G at 
 C:\Users\Lukas\.julia\packages\Factotum\KzSyl\src\Factotum.jl:44
```

Comment: Please make sure to post code (and error outputs) from the REPL, rather than an image (which doesn't display for me).

Comment: i edited the question, sorry i´m new here

Comment: Looks like this is the function: https://github.com/gragusa/Factotum.jl/blob/master/src/Factotum.jl#L44-L48 and it wants not just a matrix, but also a number? `FactorModel(Z::AbstractMatrix, numfactors)`

Comment: ohh i totally overlooked that.. Thank You !! Now it works

Comment: @mcabbott can you please put together an answer from your comment for completeness?